# check-in multiple files 200+ in one shot

Tags: svn

I'm trying to figure out how to commit large number of files (it is 250 in my case) in one shot, i.e. I don't want to break down in multiple commits. So far I've tried --targets option, or just

```
svn commit `cat mylist`
```

In both cases it seems that SVN picks only the last 100 or so files and simply ignores the rest. Is it intended behaviour? What is the usual way to commit *a lot of* files?

Thanks.

Comment: Any chance of just committing the directory that the files are in?

Answer (score 0):

`svn ci` should do it. The 'ignoring' files sounds like those files have not yet been added via `svn add`, which must happen before the commit.